# What is the cardinality of the following set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cardinals

Is the cardinality of the set

{$x|$ $x ∈ N$ and $x=1.5$}

infinite or not?

Comment: If $N$ is the set of all natural numbers, then your set is empty and thus finite.

Comment: No matter how you look at it, the second condition ensures that your set is finite, whether $N$ stands for $\mathbb{N}$ or not. $N\cap \{1.5\}$ has either 0 or 1 elements, since $\{1.5\}$ has one element.

Answer (score 3):

$1.5$ is not a natural number, so your set is empty, so is finite.